# How to show a dashed line that looks like a placeholder underneath an input fields's input value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input text field with a placeholder like `___ ___ ___` for it. Now I want those dashes to be always visible especially when the user has entered some numbers. Is a placeholder even the right thing to use here or can it be solved differently?

```html
<form action="#" class="form" name="form">

  <fieldset>
    <legend class="textform">E-mail</legend>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="tutaj wpisz adres email" class="forminput" data-error="Wpisz prawidłowy adres e-mail">
    <div class="help-block with-errors d-none">WPISZ PRAWIDŁOWY E-MAIL</div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend class="textform">Numer telefonu</legend>
    <div class="phone">
      <span class="tel">+48</span>
      <input class="forminput" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="_ _ _  _ _ _  _ _ _" id="tel">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Using ``placeholder`` would delete the pretext after typing.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem; what you are wanting *seems* like "how can I indicate the number of digits required for the telephone field", is that correct?

Comment: you can look at this if you want to create a field especially for phone numbers or international phone numbers https://www.twilio.com/blog/international-phone-number-input-html-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
You can use a wrapper element and a data attribute, as follow.

```css
.placeholder
{
    position: relative;
}

.placeholder::after
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder" data-placeholder="_ _ _  _ _ _  _ _ _">
    <input/>  
</div>
```

Comment: OP's placeholder is hard to see. Can you make it more visible?

Comment: @mplungjan Check the edited answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I guess it has to be `___  ___  ___` but that is not clearer

Comment: I suggest a mono-space font if you're hoping to get the input characters to be positioned above each underscore.